# MKMapView setVisibleMapRect not setting (sometimes)

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have an application which plots a flights route on an MKMapView. After the route is loaded, there is a small calculation which finds the north-east and south-west points. Then using the 2 points a MKMapRect is created to zoom to the rect, after setVisibleMapRect is called. This however works on small routes, but not routes typically that span more than 90 degrees.

```
NSLog(@"North East: %f, %f", northEastPoint.x, northEastPoint.y);
NSLog(@"South West: %f, %f", southWestPoint.x, southWestPoint.y);

MKMapRect swRect = MKMapRectMake(southWestPoint.x, southWestPoint.y, 0, 0);
MKMapRect neRect = MKMapRectMake(northEastPoint.x, northEastPoint.y, 0, 0); 
MKMapRect zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(neRect, swRect);
[_map setVisibleMapRect:zoomRect animated:NO];
```

For a route from Finland to Hong Kong the points are:

```
// North East: 219158701.181065, 117406780.189312
// South West: 152831738.959918, 77478198.921545
```

Which centers the map quite nicely:

[image: Finland to Hong Kong]

However a similar route from London to Hong Kong the points are:

```
// North East: 219158701.181065, 117406780.189312
// South West: 133873691.426088, 77821652.051143
```

Which does not center... stays at 0, 0

[image: London to Hong Kong]

Any ideas why?? it has been bugging me for a while. I think it might have something to do with that the route exceeds 90 degrees longitude.

Comment: in iOS worldmap is not continuous as in case of Android.(in Android if you completely zoom out you will 2-3 maps side by side in which case your code will set the mapview region correctly). in iOS for example you can try setting center of map on Australia in completely zoom out view and you will see the same region as in your second case. To set center of map on Australia MKMapview must have another mapview on right side of it. So nothing is wrong with code, it is just how MKMapView behaves.

Comment: @chatur, Ok so what can I do to fix my problem?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to fix this.

Comment: @chatur I believe this was a bug in iOS, it has now been fixed in iOS 5

Comment: For iOS 7, I this setVisibleMapRect doesn't work when it is animated. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in IOS, this has been resolved in iOS 5.1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[_map setRegion:yourRegion animated:animated]` instead